# classifying data from an ARFF in weka

Tags: weka, arff

I have an ARFF that i've loaded into the weka explorer. I'm quite new to weka but to my understanding the arff i have should be working however none of the classifiers appear to work with it?

```
@RELATION wordfrequency

@ATTRIBUTE word string
@ATTRIBUTE frequency numeric

@DATA
allah,71
ye,65
day,46
lord,21
truth,20
say,20
and,20
the,19
return,19
it,19
```

Is there something i've missed adding to the arff file? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to classify and where is the attribute for class? if you create an attribute class {c1,c2}. and filter your attributes   in weka chose `filter->unsupervised->attribute->Stringtovector` and apply after this you can classify , it work with the naive bayes and other classifiers.

```
@RELATION wordfrequency
@ATTRIBUTE word string
@ATTRIBUTE frequency numeric
@ATTRIBUTE class {c1,c2}

@DATA

allah,71,c1
ye,65,c2
day,46,c1
lord,21,c2
truth,20,c1
say,20,c2
```